# Why does Intellij IDEA Community compile code that uses runtime only dependencies?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin, dependency-management

Note: import suggestions can be disabled on a package basis. That is not the feature I'm looking for.

I am trying to declutter the intellisense/autocomplete suggestions in Intellij IDEA CE, by marking transitive dependencies as runtime only dependencies. As a specific example, say I want to remove the notorious hamcrest suggestions from the window below:

[image: cluttered suggestions]

As I am using Gradle, I thought I could solve this by making `org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3` a `testRuntimeOnly` dependency instead of a `testImplementation` dependency. As expected, after re-importing the Gradle project to the IDE, it is correctly marked as a "Runtime" dependency in the IntelliJ module:

[image]

However, this does not stop intellisense making suggestions from the excluded library. Worse than that, code that uses the "Runtime" scoped library actually compiles with the IDE tool chain, but the gradle build fails as the library is correctly excluded from the compile classpath.

At that point, I verified that I could use any code from any "Runtime" scoped dependency and the IDE would not have a problem with it.

Am I missing something here? What is the point of the "Runtime" scope if it doesn't prevent me from depending on the code directly?

Note: I am using Kotlin for JVM i.e. my source code is Kotlin but the dependencies are Java.

Comment: This can be done only on using the import/completion exclusion on the package basis. IDE intellisense will suggest the methods from the runtime dependencies as it's something available to your application which is perfectly fine to be used in the code.

Comment: @CrazyCoder It's not OK to use runtime dependencies in the code - gradle omits those libraries from the the classpath at compile time therefore the build will fail.

Comment: Martin, not sure why the android tag was added. While kotlin and a variant of IntelliJ are often used for Android development, this question applies much more generally to any kotlin project using IntelliJ, and possibly any java project too. Changed it back for now unless you had some other reason that I'm missing.